# MSSQL Service 50% Resources

Tags: 16.04, server, mssql

I've been doing some testing on the current version of [MSSQL on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017).  I'm using a DigitalOcean droplet to test using Ubuntu V16.  Up front, MSSQL for linux recommended memory size is 2GB and that is the amount memory allocated to this droplet.

```
user@user:~$ uname -a
Linux user4.4.0-128-generic #154-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 25 14:15:18 UTC 2018 x86_                                                                                                             64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user@user:~$ lsb_release
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Sometime after installing, I've noticed that the service uses roughly half of the system memory resource.

```
user@user:~$ ps aux | grep mssql
mssql     1847  0.9 44.6 1332620 914160 ?      Sl   Jun11 389:31 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

I want to stop and start this service on demand, rather than at system startup.  `systemctl remove mssql-server` so it doesn't start on reboot.  `sudo service mssql stop` or `sudo service mssql start` to develop on that database.

My question is, why is it using so much memory?  Is it this bad for everyone?  What are some things that have been done to improve it?

Comment: Ask Microsoft those questions.  Only Microsoft can provide guidance on why it uses memory and whether it can be improved.  MSSQL on Linux is closed source.

Comment: @ThomasWard I agree that that should be the normal path.  But I think we might agree that the MS community around using their products in *nix environments is sparse at best.  I thought it better to ask Ubuntu users what they've experienced.

Comment: @Wiking lol truth